# Surface area integral problem

Tags: calculus, surface-integrals

> $$Z = \log (x^2 + y^2) $$
>   $$1< x^2 + y^2  < 5 $$
>   Find the area of the surface.

**My attempt:** If $z=f(x,y)$, then the normal vector is 
$$\sqrt { \frac{df}{dx} ^2 + \frac{df}{dy} ^2 + 1} $$
which gives me $$\sqrt { \displaystyle\frac{4}{(x^2 + y^2)} +1}$$

Now I parameterize $x$ and $y$ using polar coordinates:

Let $x = r \cos t$ and $y = r \sin t$, where $1 \le r \le \sqrt{5}$ and $0 \le t \le 2\pi$.

My normal vector would then be $\sqrt{\frac{4}{r^2} +1}$.

Multiplying by the Jacobian for polar coordinates , I get $\sqrt{4+r^2}$.

Then I have to integrate that with respect to $dr$ and $dt$ to get the surface area, is that right??

Comment: Yes, you've got it.